# Why do I have to do a git rebase --skip (git svn)

Tags: git, git-svn, git-rebase

I did a `git svn rebase` to merge in remote changes and get a conflict. Resolved the conflict manually and tried `git rebase --continue`, however it didn't let me do it.

Then I found [this](http://tech.hickorywind.org/articles/2008/06/10/larry-vs-the-git-rebase-merge-conflict):

> If it complains about "did you forget to call 'git add'?", then
>   evidently your edit turned the conflict into a no-op change. Do a "git
>   rebase --skip" to skip it. (Very weird, but true.)

Can anyone explain to me why `git rebase --continue` didn't work and I had to do a `git rebase --skip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
git rebase --skip
```

Because with your merging you don't mannually change anything.

`git rebase --continue` only is used when you change the conflicted file in merging.

`git rebase --skip` is used when you do not change the conflicted file in merging.

Comment: Evidently your edit turned the conflict into a no-op change. It's a no-op change. So could you manually change the merge conflict differently again? and after that try `git rebase --continue`

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what the `no-op change` means? Also, what do you mean with change the merge conflict differently?

Comment: No-op change means that the changes you did manually is the same as the changes the merge tool recommends you.

Comment: And changing the merge conflict differently is to merge again, but in this time, change the conflicted file a little.